# Online Subscription Payment System

Tags: payment, subscription

I am looking for some kind of online subscription payment system which is kind of like Spreedly and Recurly but it either has a cheap monthly price or they take a % per transaction.

What other options are there available? I don't really want to manage subscriptions myself and I'm looking to use as many web services as I can :-)

All suggestions and discussion welcome...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I found [chargify.com](http://chargify.com) - looks interesting and cheap but it works only for businesses located in couple of countries